# How do I count the letter N in an output file, which is a list of strings written to a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**SOLVED**

I need to be able to count the amount of 'N' in all strings in the output file. But when I print the result I always get a 0 or None. Does anyone see the mistake in my code?

```
def ncount(filename):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for words in file:
            if words in file == "N":
                count = count + 1
                return count
count = ncount("output_seq.txt")
print(count)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
["GATTTTCTATGACATCTAGAAGAAAAAGAAAGACTATAAGATGTATAAAAACAAGAGGNNCNGAGAAAATCGAGACAGGTGGTGAGAATCTGCCGAATTAN", 
"AACATTGCTGAGAGGTTCGATCGTGATCCCTGCAAGAAAAAATAAAGGTGGAGATGATNNCNCAATGTATGTTGTCTCGTCACACTGGTTTAATGATTTTN", 
"CTTTTTTTTAAATATTTCGGGCGGTAATTTTTTCTGCCATCTTTTTCACTAAGAAAACTTTCAGGCGTTGTTAAGCGGTGGAATCTATAGAGCTGTCTCTT", 
"ATGTATCTAACGAGACAGCAATGGGAATTTTGTATTAAAAAAAAGAAGAAATACATATTTTGAAACAGGAATGTTGTTTGATTTTTAAAGAAAAAAGGAAA", 
"TCCAGACGCAAAANNNNNNNNTTTTTGTCTCAAGACTACAGTACCCTGGGTCTCGCCACGAAAATTGTTTGTTAAATGAGAAAATGTGTGCGCCTTTAAAG", 
""]
```

This is a dummy file, containing only 5 sequences. The actual file contains thousands of these strings

The output I keep receiving is:

```
0
```

Comment: `for words in file.read()`, though I would do `for line in file.readlines()`

Comment: You shouldn't use `file` as a variable as well since it is an object in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file.readlines()` to iterate over the file line by line as a string. You can then simply use the `count()` method which counts the occurrence of a term in a string:

```
def ncount(filename):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile.readlines():
            count += line.count('N')
    return count
count = ncount("somefile.txt")
print(count)
```

For your `"output_seq.txt"` file, this outputs `16`.

Comment: I tried this code, but I still get 0. Could this have something to do with the way I parsed the file in order to get this output file?

Comment: Add `print(line)` inside the for loop & include the output in your post.

Comment: I did it, the output remains 0. See the original post

Comment: I'm asking the output of `print(line)` (not `print(count)`), to check how the file is being read.

Comment: @Luke, The code above works. Are you sure you are reading in the correct file?

Comment: Sorry something came up, but i copy pasted the code into another file and there it works. somehow the earlier code interferes with it somehow. Yet I do not know where the mistake is

Comment: no need in `readlines` method, `myfile` is an iterable already

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't necessarily need to have a Python function/module but just looking for an adhoc solution to get the number of 'N' occurrences per line, you can just do it directly from a Unix terminal using `awk`:

```
cat your_file_name | awk '{print gsub(/N/,"")}'
```

This prints to the output each line number (1, 2, 3, etc.) and the respective number of 'N' occurrences.

**EDIT:** To run this bash command through Python you can use the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

input_file = 'my-input-file'
cmd = "cat " + input_file + " | awk '{print gsub(/N/," + '"")}' + "'"
print(cmd)

# Unix cmd call
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# read STDOUT and STDERR
stdout, _ = p.communicate()
stdout = str(stdout, "utf-8")

# convert stdout string to a list of integers (with num of 'N' occurrences per line)
n_count = [int(i) for i in stdout.split('\n')[:-1]]
print(n_count)
```

You don't even need to store the output from the bash command into an output file. You can just read it into a string (`stdout`), which you can then split into a list of integers (`n_count`).

However, since you want to implement this in Python I would advise using native Python functions instead of embedding this adhoc solution from `bash`.

Comment: I have to create a pipeline which analysis big data files through one job script. Is it possible to do this with ```import os``` and then write the output to an output file? I need the number on 'N' occurrences, how I obtain this result doesn't matter

Comment: you can do that with the `subprocess` module. I edited my answer showing that

Answer (score 0):

This code is less efficient than glhr's but it will help you see what is going on. It will print each character (even quotes or blanks) and append "found an N" when it finds one:

```
def ncount(filename):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
        for words in input_file:
            for letter in words:
                print(letter)
                if letter == "N":
                    print('%s found an N' % letter)
                    count = count + 1
                else:
                    print(letter)

        return count

  count = ncount("output_seq.txt")
  print(count)
```

part of the output:

```
A
G
G
A
A
G
G
G
G
N
N found an N
N
N found an N
C
C
N
N found an N
G
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finaly able to get the script to work. Thanks to everyone who gave me tips and offered their help with my problem.

This code was a small piece of a bigger script, which I thought was working fine. But in the end there was a line of code that somehow interfered with this piece of code. I used @glhr his or hers code, and I altered the rest of my script to make it work.

Here is the rest of my script.

```
# import the biopython packages
from Bio import SeqIO

# parse the fastq file into a list of records
with open("output_rec_qual.txt", "w") as f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse("dummy.txt", "fastq"):
        # write the id and the corresponding quality scores to a separate file
        f.write(record.format("qual"))
f.close()


# read the file again, this time parse the sequences into another output file. In order to perform the n-count
def readfastq(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        while True:
            file.readline()
            seq = file.readline().rstrip()
            file.readline()
            file.readline()
            f = open("output_seq.txt", 'a')
            f.write(seq)
            if len(seq) == 0:
                break
    return seq


seq = readfastq("dummy.txt")



# n-count
def ncount(filename):
    count = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            count += line.count('N')
    return count


count = ncount("output_seq.txt")
print(count)
```